# Ganache provider not working with web3

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ganache

I am trying to run a test script for my smart contract but ganache provider is not being accepted by web3 here is my code.

```
    const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

beforeEach(()=>{
  web3.eth.getAccounts()
    .then(fetchedAccounts=>{
      console.log(fetchedAccounts);
    });
});

describe('Inbox',()=>{
  it('deploys a contract',()=>{

  });
});
```

This is error message

```
/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:720
      throw new Error('Please provide an valid Web3 provider');
            ^
Error: Please provide an valid Web3 provider
    at ProviderResolver.resolve (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:720:13)
    at Web3.AbstractWeb3Module (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/web3-core/dist/web3-core.cjs.js:27:51)
    at new Web3 (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.cjs.js:30:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/test/Inbox.test.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ace/Desktop/ETH/inbox/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
    at startMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:439:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ace/.npm/_logs/2019-02-07T14_24_38_841Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

web3 version 1.0.0-beta.37 solves this problem
just uninstall previous web3

```
npm uninstall web3
```

and re install it

```
npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.37
```

Comment: Current version is `1.0.0-beta.41`. There are known problems in 38 and 39, but why use 37???